# Convert UTC offset to USA time zone with Joda Time

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

Given a UTC offset, i.e. -5, can I determine the USA time zone using Joda Time? One of Pacific, Mountain, Central, Easter is sufficient. I can't use Java 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *only* have an offset, then no, you can't. -5 could be Central Daylight Time or Eastern Standard Time, for example. Likewise an offset of -7 could be Pacific Daylight Time or Mountain Standard Time.

If you have an offset and a date/time at which it was valid, you could make a pretty good guess - but only if you assume that everywhere in the US switches to daylight saving, and that everywhere does it at the same time - [but that's not entirely the case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States).

Answer (score 1):

You can always obtain a timezone offset from a timezone ID but the reverse of it is not possible because the same timezone offset can be applicable to many timezone IDs. Check [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to find many examples of it.

Note that some timezone IDs can have different timezone offsets (e.g. because of [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) or when [a country decides to change it](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2018/05/04/the-brief-history-of-north-koreas-time-zone/)). However, you do not need to worry about it as long as the timezone database of your Java installation is up-to-date.

[`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) has been designed to adjust the timezone offset automatically according to the moment you use it for.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(10, 20);
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");

        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 27), time, zoneId));
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 28), time, zoneId));

        // ############# Obtaining timezone offset from ZoneId #############
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2021, Month.MARCH, 28), time);

        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, zoneId).getOffset());
        // Alternatively
        System.out.println(zoneId.getRules().getOffset(ldt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-27T10:20Z[Europe/London]
2021-03-28T10:20+01:00[Europe/London]
+01:00
+01:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/8oqfyc)

The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>